# php date return 1970-01-01 08:00:00

Tags: php, strtotime

```
<?php 
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 0);
 ?>
```

//Result: 1970-01-01 08:00:00


My question: The second parameter of function date is 0, It should be 1970-01-01 **00**:00:00.
Why it is 1970-01-01 **08**:00:00 ?

I set config in php.ini

[Date]

`date.timezone=Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh`

//Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh: UTC + 7 (GMT + 7)

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Please edit your post title to ensure that it can be looked up by future users, the current title does not provide a description and is ambiguous. I hope you have a good time here!

Comment: Is the time correct when you type `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`? It sounds like the server time is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> The Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970

As you see, the beginning is started by the UTC timezone. That means that it was `8:00` in `Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh` when the Unix epoch started.

If you need to get `0:00` you have to set negative second parameter

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'); // Set UTC timezone
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", -(8 * 60 * 60));
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3479d159674cd6eff1b807cfaf60730a54f5a316)

Answer (score 0):

[Date php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) and [Default timezone set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) if you want to set your current time:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

you don't need the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

date() always shows the local time. That’s for you Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh. The gmdate() function is used to display the UTC/GMT time.

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", 0);
//Result: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

You can also use DateTime. If DateTime is created from a timestamp, the internal time zone is always UTC.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('@0');
echo $dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//Result: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

You don't need to change your default timezone for either option.